# Failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: magento2

I ran the setup:upgrade command and I'm getting the following error when I open my website

```
Warning: include(/var/www/html/var/view_preprocessed/html/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/base/templates/root.phtml): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

I thought this was a permissions issue but I ran chown on the entire magento folder recursively and this seems to do nothing. There are no files in the view_preprocessed folder even after running setup:upgrade and setup:di:compile so I believe that is the issue but I don't know how to solve it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try running followings in given order.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
rm -rf var/{cache,di,generation,page_cache,view_preprocessed}
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

--- Update ---

Your module should be working. You can check it by removing the content area from inside the new module.

Admin:
create Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/default.xml with following content.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceContainer name="content" remove="true"/>
</page>
```

Clean the cache and refresh the admin section. The main content area should not be visible. Otherwise, you have something wrong with your module. Check all file/folder name. Pay attention to the case.

Comment: I ran these commands and they worked but the module I was installing now shows it is enabled but doesn't show up in the admin section or under system > advanced for disable modules

Comment: Does your module listed under app/etc/config.php?

Comment: Yes it shows up there with a 1 next to the name

Comment: I'm not seeing it in the vendor folder. I only see it under app/code/vendor_name

Comment: sorry for the confusion, replace  Vendor/Module/ with your actual vendor and module name. E.g. Magento/Checkout

Comment: No I understand what you are saying but the only items that show up in the vendor folder are modules that I installed through composer. modules that I installed by copying the files over are all located in app/code

Comment: Yes, create view/adminhtml/layout/default.xml under your module in app/code

Comment: I cleared my cache and created that file and it doesn't look like anything has changed. I should mention that I was able to install this same module on another server with no issues and it used the same exact code

Comment: Are there any differences between servers? Like Windows, Linux

Comment: no they are both linux centos 7 servers

Comment: could you provide the directory file structure of your module?

Comment: I can just send you the full code if that helps

Comment: gihan.seneviratna@gmail.com

Comment: I'm not sure how to send a rar file over gmail but I removed the module and tried to install the old version that worked just fine and it is doing the same thing. I'm thinking the files have nothing to do with it. I'm thinking it is a database issue because that is the only possibility left imo

Comment: Try, deleting the module from the setup_module table and running setup: upgrade again.