# Production mode won't geneate files inside var/view_processed folder

Tags: magento2, permissions, production-mode

When I open the frontend and backend I always got an error like this:

> "Warning:
>   include(/var/www/test.com/var/view_preprocessed/html/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/base/templates/root.phtml):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /var/www/test.com/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php on
>   line 312";

I checked inside `var/view_processed` folder and it only has 1 css file.

I already tried this [solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/171676/67755), but it's not working, I already set the permission for var folder to 775 but it's not working either

```
chmod -R 775 var
```

The only solution for me right now is change the Magento mode from production to developer.

```
bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

When I change to developer mode it's working fine, but when I change back to production mode the same error appear. How to fix this error for production mode?

Comment: Can you set all files to 644 permission and directories to 755 of your magento root directory? Also try 777 to magento_root/var for testing.

Comment: @SukumarGorai still not working

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/138800/69 redploy & be sure to purge all caches. `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`